# command KLogPermitNonKernelFacility is currently not permitted

Tags: rsyslog, ubuntu-16.04

I've setup loggly to for syslog alerts among other things and am getting the following error repeatedly in syslog.

```
command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
```

Running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 4.4.0-42-generic

The server seems to be running fine otherwise. From what I can tell this informs rsyslog to allow non-kernal events into syslog, which is what I want. I am unsure beyond that.

Also receiving this one

```
Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
```

I'm a very, very unwilling dev-ops, sorry in advance.

*edit: restared syslog service, problem persists.

*edit: supressed /dev/xconsole errors, KLogPermitNonKernelFacility error persists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is is a known bug.

[Bug#1531622](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1531622)
KLogPermitNonKernelFacility - it's legacy parameter which is no longer used. 
To remove the error, locate and comment out the following line `$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on` in the file `rsyslog.conf`

[Bug#830046](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/830046)
If the device `/dev/xconsole` is not present on you system, you can locate it like this:

```
daemon.*;mail.*;\
news.err;\
*.=debug;*.=info;\
*.=notice;*.=warn |/dev/xconsol
```

and comment it out, or replace `xconsole` with `console`.

Comment: Unfortunately bug #1531622 has been fixed for Ubuntu 17.04, but not for 16.04 (LTS not withstanding).  The fix proposed here gets a little messier when buried in third party docker apps and the like.

Answer (score 2):

Found at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/459730

```
sudo service rsyslog stop

sudo mknod -m 640 /dev/xconsole c 1 3

sudo chown syslog:adm /dev/xconsole

sudo service rsyslog start
```

Verify it is working with reload as well:

```
sudo service rsyslog reload

sudo tail /var/log/messages
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't fix it for me. I had also to change the check as follows: `sudo service rsyslog restart` and `sudo tail /var/log/syslog`.